# Jquery - multilevel vertical menu: can't select last submenu because it dissapears

Tags: php, jquery, css, menu

I've created some vertical multi-level menu, but I have some problem with it. I dont know how to prevent dissapear 3rd lv menu, I want make it not sticky to the rest of options.

http://jsfiddle.net/BvkmN/1/

Please for any advices :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your mouseleave event is happening because there is a gap between the second and third levels.

You can either:

Change the position of the 3rd level so there is no gap and hence no mouseleave event:

```
l = $(this).width()+9;
```

or

Put a delay on the hide method on mouseleave, to give the user time to get across the gap before it hides it.